# Javascript if code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is wrong with this code piece of code:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > 290) && ($(window).width > 500) {

} else {

}
```

I want to check both - the width of the screen and scroll size

Comment: "_What is wrong..._": 1. Indentation. 2. Parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a pair of parentheses around the entire `if` condition. Also, `width` is a method, so you have to call it:

```
if (($(window).scrollTop() > 290) && ($(window).width() > 500)) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: You win, noticing the `width` problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean to use this?

```
if( $(window).scrollTop() > 290  &&  $(window).width() > 500 ) {
```

I took out the extra parentheses you were using to possibly group the individual conditions.

(and I'm late to the party mentioning that `.width` needs to be `.width()`, that @Blender realized)

Answer (score 1):

You have too many or too few parenthesis.

```
   if( $(window).scrollTop() > 290  &&  $(window).width() > 500 ) {

   } else {


   }
```

Comment: The code is still not working `.width` is not a property but a method.